# Problems FT5306 USB Touchscreen

Tags: usb, driver, touchscreen

First of all, sorry for my terrible languache.

I bought 7" display with usb touchscreen from [Eleduino](http://www.eleduino.com/7-0-inch-Hdmi-touch-with-USB-touch-Display-Support-Raspberry-pi-Bnana-PI-Banana-Pro-Beaglebone-bone-p10442.html). It works fine with Raspibian distros presented by vendor, but I want to connect it to my RPi B+ with OpenELEC on board.

Ok, I've downloaded OpenELEC source code from github and build it. But touchscreen didn't work with it.

Use `lsusb` to get info about device: here it is: `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:0005 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd`. Cool! Google told me, what it EETI's eGalax touchscreen, so, I try to install drivers into my RPi. And without any result. EETI support gave me an advise to ask FocalTech support, but they didn't give answer.

One attention. Touchscreen works on FocalTech FT5306 chip. This chip provides i2c interface, but not in this lcd :D. This touchscreen connects to RPi by usb -> STM32 -> FT5306.

By the way, Eleduino support didn't want to help me at all.

So, I try to build OpenELEC linux kernel with all avaliable support for usb touchscreens and usb devices. Without any result, but I found next in dmesg:

```
[  970.528797] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[  970.625619] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0eef, idProduct=0005
[  970.625656] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  970.625673] usb 1-1.4: Product: By ZH851
[  970.625687] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: RPI_TOUCH
[  970.625701] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: RÿhgWUC`g
[  970.652930] hid-generic 0003:0EEF:0005.0002: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Device [RPI_TOUCH By ZH851] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.4/input0
```

and in /dev I found 2 new devices: /dev/hidraw0 and /dev/usb/hiddev0. When I use `cat` for this device nodes and touch connected touchscreen I get some unreadable data on console. I thought, what the problem is easy: Linux can't understand what it's input device! Ok. I found tslib. Build it with support for hiddev, but after configurating tslib and start ts_calibrate it tolds me next:

```
xres = 1, yres = 1
tslib: Selected device is not a Linux input event device
```

Now, I don't know what to do... Please, could somebody help me?

Comment: Does it create something in `/dev/input/`?

Comment: No, it's not. It's only creates '/dev/hidraw0' and '/dev/usb/hiddev0', but the Raspibian distro what avaliable on eleduino store creates '/dev/input/event0'.   By the way, I found some drivers at eleduino website, but they are for 3.12.x kernel (my version is 4.0.4), and install script only replace kernel modules and image from installed distro to downloaded binaries.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/X85UYRQQ is the result of dmsg of distro, where my touchscreen works. http://pastebin.com/g8fjm8ix is the result of `diff -qr 3.12.26 4.0.4` kernels, there 3.12.26 is a dirrectory with drivers from eleduino and 4.0.4 is OpenELEC kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution I found works on Debian based OS. For another Linux distro you will need to make some changes in install script. Otherwise, this solutions only works in next scenario: it's emits left mouse button click event at the place of your's finger. Good for most ways as I think.

Well, I've just planed to start learning Linux kernel programming, and this is a good start for practice. I'd write some code (https://github.com/ArhiChief/eleduino_ts), so, if anyone will give me advises or something like that, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As of tslib-1.2 there is a raw input module for waveshare that seems to support your device using `module_raw waveshare <vendorID>:<productID>` in `ts.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like someone find answer. https://github.com/derekhe/wavesahre-7inch-touchscreen-driver. I'll try to use his code as a start point.

Comment: Please do come back and tell us how it went.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: We're [trying a new policy with regard to informationless link-only answers here](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538). If this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.